# Run Jenkins job immediately

Tags: jenkins

I have a very lightweight job that should be executed immediately when it is triggered, rather than waiting an hours for current jobs to finish.

As I understand, a *flyweight* task is what I want. It will create a ephemeral executor, just for that task.

How can I make a job be run as flyweight?

Comment: firstpoint why do you require flyweight ? is there any parallel tasks you going to perform in instances.. you have option to make flywieght tasks using workflow plugin.. again you have to tailor it for your own needs.. if you explain bit deeper, we can help you more..

Comment: @DevD, the end goal is the title. I want to run a Jenkins job immediately without waiting for existing jobs, or killing existing jobs. Flyweight tasks are just an idea I had for how this could be done.

Comment: for that you can enable start jobs paralel jobs in configuration

Comment: @DevD, but that doesn't solve the problem. I'm still limited by the number of executors. I have some intensive, long jobs, and then a high priority very quick job (*flyweight* one might say). And I want to know how to create a flyweight job. Certainly, it has a use; otherwise, it would not exist.

Comment: Still the issue exist...??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out this [FlyWeightProject Plugin](https://gitlab.cern.ch/lhcb-core/Jenkins-FlyWeightProject-Plugin). It is an extension of the Freestyle type that runs in Flyweight.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently had the same problem. My company has a lot of jenkins projects and some have more precedence over others, and we limit the number of executors to only 4.

Therefore, we decided to create some slaves, instead of always building on the master. Create a slave node that only builds your "very lightweight job".

Go to `Manage Jenkin -> Manage nodes -> New node -> Dumb slave`.

Then configure your slave node to your liking. Now configure the "very lightweight job". **Make sure that** `This build is parameter` is checked, then `Add parameter -> Node`.

Then select the slave node that you just created. There are a lot of configurations, such as which node do you want to default, but I think you can customize that to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU the issue is that all your executors are occupied when it comes to running this high priority job.

What about:

- Establishing another slave node; in a VM, for instance; with an appropriate number of executors, in case there are more of these high priority jobs
- Assigning a label like *high-priority* to this new node
- Restricting where this high priority job can be run to this *high-priority* label
- Assigning a label like *long-running* to all other nodes
- Restricting where all other jobs can be run to this *long-running* label

Another possibility is to:

- Configure the new node's *Usage: Only build jobs with label restrictions matching this node*
- Restrict where the high priority job can be run to the new node

  This avoids having to create and assign labels to all jobs, as mentioned above, but is less flexible for future adaptions and extensions.

Comment: Does this require a whole new machine/VM?

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes, it does.